# EasyAdmin 3 - Nested one to one form if association is null?

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin3

I found a part of my answer on StackOverflow ([EasyAdmin 3 - CRUD with nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999220/easyadmin-3-crud-with-nested-form)) but I have an additional problem.

I have a Person entity with an User entity with a one to one relation between the both (0 or 1 user).

I would to manage the user since the person form in EasyAdmin, but if the user is null, I have an error.

How to test the current object in EasyAdmin to conditionize the user fields ?

Thank you.